# Как передать строки из bash в msfconsole?

Tags: bash, shell, консоль, io, взлом

После запуска metasploit framework console (msf) открывает свою консоль:

msf >

Как **из внешнего bash скрипта** подавать комманды на консоль msf?

*Например*, что бы при запуске, скрипта в консоль msf автоматически вводилась применялась строка set LHOST 192.168.1.1 как при нажатии клавиши Enter, что приведёт к такому результату:

msf > set LHOST 192.168.1.1

LHOST => 192.168.1.1 (переменная LHOST установлена)

Answer (score 0):

Вопросрешился подключением expect.