# Как выполнить команду?

Tags: bash

У меня есть код (ниже). После запуска программы он запускает игровой сервер, а затем вводит и выполняет команду "help". Но эта команда не срабатывает в игровой консоли, а срабатывает отдельно в корневой директории.
Как мне выполнить эту команду для игрового сервера?

```
#!/bin/bash
   START_SERVER="./start_server"
      "$START_SERVER" $@
     while true; do
     sleep 10
     COMMAND="help"
      "$COMMAND" $@
     done
```

Comment: Наверное надо пайпить в стандартный ввод запущенного сервера `echo "command" | server`

Comment: Что-то я вообще не пойму, где тут асинхронность...

Comment: `echo "command" | server` как написали выше. Если сервер не "понимает" этого, выложите скрипт `./start_server` чтобы тут поняли каким образом там происходит ввод и можно было что-то подправить. Как вариант - использовать [expect](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940427/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-passphrase-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-ssh-add/940446#940446)

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1108441/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830651/178576)

Comment: Вот в том и проблема, что скрипт с закрытым кодом, поэтому я и пытаюсь какими-либо другими способами выполнять команды.